# Separate list of "letter number" (chess locations) into separate lists

Tags: python, list

Just wondering if there is a more pythonic way of accomplishing the following:

```
def safe_pawns(pawns):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in pawns:
        x += i[0]
        y += i[1]
```

Input will always be in the form of ({"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"}). With alpha first and numerals second.
I have looked around the python docs and closest i could find was zip, however i cant work out how to apply this function in this situation.
Would appreciate any advice. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks, Yes it would probably be easier this way. I am trying to write a function that will determine if the pawns are safe on the board. with alpha a numerals being the columns and rows of the board respectively. A pawn is safe if another is diagonally behind it.
Maybe even a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> records = {"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"}
>>> x, y = zip(*records)
>>> x
('g', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e')
>>> y
('5', '4', '4', '3', '4', '2', '3')
```

Comment: The question is about converting a list of strings to two sequences, not to a sequence of pairs.

Comment: You don't need to map the elements of `records` to `list`s; `str`s are iterable and thus will work as arguments to `zip`.

Comment: Thanks! May i ask what the '*' Does in this situation? Thank you

Comment: `*` expands the argument sequence so that instead of one argument, which is a set, `zip` gets all the set elements as individual arguments. That's why it zips them all together at once.

Answer (score 3):

One solution that is shorter but still ends up with two lists is `x, y = [p[0] for p in pawns], [p[1] for p in pawns]`. It does feel like there should be something with less redundancy, however. This also scans the set twice. Edit: sberry's `zip(*pawns)` is shorter and performs better, and is very idiomatic. Forgot about that one.